# How to use dir and copy together to search directories and copy to a folder?

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to search a specified folder and its subdirectories for file(s), then copy them to a specified folder somewhere else. Is it possible to use `dir` and `copy` with a pipe?

```
dir /s foo???.txt | copy g:\someplace
```

The above doesn't work. The left side of the pipe finds what I want it to, but I can't get it to copy the found files. I'm using Windows 7 command prompt.

Comment: What type of file do you need out of curiosity? Would a wildcard not suffice?

Comment: I need to use the wildcards (???--"?" is a single digit wildcard ) in the command such that the above would capture foo_42, foo_01, etc and those would be in various subfolders.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just use `xcopy`:

```
xcopy /s foo???.txt g:\someplace
```

This will hold the directory structure.

If you don't want the directory structure you can do the following:

```
for /r %i in (foo???.txt) do xcopy /Y "%i" g:\someplace
```

If you are using this in a batchfile you should double the `%` like this:

```
for /r %%i in (foo???.txt) do xcopy /Y "%%i" g:\someplace
```

Comment: Actually, I need to tweek it a bit. Can it be done without keeping the directory structure?

Comment: Haha, that's what i was afraid of :) (that's why I specifically stated it). But what would you do with duplicate filenames? It can't be done with xcopy itself but you could do it with piping something to robocopy (or maybe just copy but in a batchfile). What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: Windows 7. There will not be any duplicates for my application.

Comment: Added the method for copying to one directory. Luckily no need for robocopy. Just use `for /r`.

Comment: You rock. I wish I could upvote you again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

with Powershell u can run this:

```
cmd.exe /c dir *.txt /s /b | copy -Destination d:\md
```

part cmd.exe part Powershell
bit more understandable
but there overlapping